# Count elements who got specific values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can't figure out formula for counting Code which got 4 and 5.
First I take unique list of code in D column, then I need count of 4 and 5 in E column but how?

[image]

Comment: Why does 1004 appear twice in your "unique list" (column D)? Is that just an error or am I missing something?

Comment: @Gravitate good question) I used stored excel function for that but have no idea why is twice

Comment: What do you mean by "stored excel function"? Which function in particular? Also, in column E, are you looking for a count of 4/5s for EACH code? Or just a single total sum of 4/5s for ALL codes?

Comment: @Gravitate in Data->advanced there is advanced filter, there you can copy unique result to another column. For each code

Comment: Ah ok... one of your 1004 codes in column A might have a trailing space, making it different to the other one? P.S. When I need to get a unique list, rather than using the advanced filter, I usually copy the data, then "Remove Duplicates" from the data tab. Same result, just different method :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't entirely clear if you are looking for a count for each code, or if you just want a single total for all of them.
However, the simplest way to do it would be:

[image]

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$37,{4,5},$A$2:$A$37,$D2))
```

The `COUNTIFS` function will return an array of 2 values. One value being the count of 4s for a particular code, and the other being the count of 5s for that code.
This is wrapped in a `SUM` to add those two values together.

These counts for each code can then be summed together into a total if required.

### Avoid the array...

In response to the OP stating that the `{4,5}` array isn't working...
I am not sure why that would be, but the single `COUNTIFS` formula with an array of multiple criteria can be split out into multiple `COUNTIFS`. This is a bit more verbose but does avoid the array:

```
=SUM(
    COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$37,4,$A$2:$A$37,$D2), 
    COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$37,5,$A$2:$A$37,$D2)
)
```

***EDIT***

Thanks to a suggestion by @JosWoolley, the reason that the array criteria is not working for the OP may be to do with regional differences in horizontal array separators.

e.g. Depending on the region settings `,` is not universally used as a horizontal array separator.

However, `;` is universally used as a vertical separator, and in this instance, it doesn't matter if the array is separated horizontally or vertically, therefore, it should be safe to simply swap `,` for `;`.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$37,{4;5},$A$2:$A$37,$D2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, saved a lot of time and energy) One more question {4,5} doesnt but if put one of them {4} it works. Any idea how to solve?

Comment: Erm... im not sure why the {4,5} array won't work for you. But you can always split it out into two almost identical `COUNTIFS` - `=SUM(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$37,4,$A$2:$A$37,$D2), COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$37,5,$A$2:$A$37,$D2))` This will do exactly the same thing but is a bit more verbose and avoids having an array within the formula.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, it's possible that the OP is not using an English-language version of Excel, which might mean that the separator for horizontal array constants is something other than the comma. AFAIK the separator for vertical array constants is universally the semicolon; as such, it would have been safer for you to post `{4;5}` instead of `{4,5}`.

Comment: Guys you helped me a lot. I appreciate your time.

Comment: @JosWoolley Good catch. Thank you. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Gravitate Ok, but re "*to do with regional differences in array separators - , vs ;*", just to clarify that the semicolon is not the equivalent of the comma for different language versions; as I said, the semicolon is universally the separator in *vertical* arrays, as far as I know. The separator for *horizontal* arrays (which is the comma for English-language versions) tends to vary more - I have seen both the backslash and period used for different language versions.

Comment: @JosWoolley Yes, I understood. I was just being lazy. Sorry. I have expanded further. It should be clear to anyone looking from your answer and comments anyway. :)

Answer (score 3):

Two options:

```
=MMULT(COUNTIFS(A:A,D2#,B:B,{4,5}),{1;1})

=BYROW(D2#,LAMBDA(ζ,SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,ζ,B:B,{4,5}))))
```

both of which assume that your list in `D2` is a spilled range.

Note that, if you are not using an English-language version of Excel, the separators within the array constants `{4,5}` and `{1;1}` may require amendment.